# I have an API User id and secret. Do I have everything I need to get an API Token?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, security-token

*Background: I'm developing a rails webapp that sends emails. I'm using the MarketingCloudSDK gem to interact with the salesforce API, ultimately to use the triggered emails feature.*

I'm not the salesforce admin for my organization, so I requested someone set up an API keypair for me, citing the following instructions that I pieced together from salesforce documentation websites ([here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm)):

1. Go to Marketing Cloud | Administration | Installed Packages.
2. Click New.
3. Give the package a name and description.
4. Save the package. Once the package is saved, you see important details about the package. See Installed Packages Definitions for more information about each field. You see the Package ID, JWT Signing Secret, and Source Account only for packages created in your account.
5. Under Components, click Add Component.
6. Select API Integration.
7. Save the component. Under the component details, you find the Client ID and Client Secret. Use these credentials with the API’s authentication service to get OAuth access tokens that authenticate your API calls.

Eventually, I was given an ID and secret, but they belong to an API User, not an API Integration. I tried posting them to https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken with curl anyway, and I get {"message":"Unauthorized","errorcode":1,"documentation":""}.

Am I missing something? It seems like I should be able to use these credentials in some way to interact with the API, but I have not been able to find how, and while there's plenty of documentation on how to create an API User, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on what to do once you have one.

tl;dr: I have the credentials for an API user. How can I use them to get an API access token?

Comment: Generally you need the username, _password_, and secret. In many applications the password must be entered as `passwordsecret`; VSCode extension `ForceCode` is a notable example in my mind.

Comment: You need to check if the user who owns the access keys has apis enabled

Comment: @JaredT - doesn't seem to be the case here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm#!

Comment: Seems so. I'd do as @Data_Kid suggests and first verify that the user created by your admin does in fact have API access.

Comment: @Data_Kid I can see the user in email>admin>my users, but the only fields I see are Name, Reply Email Address, Notification Email Address, Username, External Key, Time Zone, Culture Code, and Salesforce.com Status. Nothing about API access. Salesforce.com Status is just Not Integrated with a link to Integrate (only field I can interact with), but that fails. It asks for a Salesforce.com Username to integrate with, and when I give it mine (non API User), it says "The given username does not exist within your Salesforce organization." which is just wrong.

Comment: The user needs to have api access. Tell your admin to switch it on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to designate an API user:

1. *Admin*
2. *My Users*
3. click on the user's name
4. *Edit*
5. check the *API user* checkbox
6. *Save*

Once the user has been designated, you can assign API permissions:

1. *Admin*
2. *My Users*
3. check the box next to the user
4. *Manage Roles* in the toolbar
5. *Edit Permissions*
6. *Email*
7. *Admin*
8. *API Access*
9. *WebService API*
10. check the box next to *Allow*

Here are the steps for [installing a package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm) and [configuring a Client ID and Client Secret](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm) to authenticate your REST API calls:

1. Log into Marketing Cloud
2. Hover over your user name in the upper right corner
3. Click *Administration*
4. In the *Account* drop-down, click *Installed Packages*
5. Click the *New* button in the upper right corner
6. Give your package a name and click *Save*
7. Click the *Add Component* button at the bottom
8. Choose *API Integration*
9. Click *Next*
10. Check the permissions appropriate for your use-case.  Typically you would check all options in *Channels > Email* and all in *Data > Data Extensions*.
11. Click *Save*
12. The *Client ID* and *Client Secret* are now configured and ready to use in your application.
13. Use the REST API tool of choice to request an Access Token for authentication.  Once you have a token, you're ready to interact with the SFMC objects.

For authorizations, the endpoint is `https://auth.exacttargetapis.com`.

Once everything's configured, try requesting a token:

```
POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "clientId": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FROM_APP_CENTER",
    "clientSecret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_APP_CENTER"
}
```

The endpoint for all of the other SFMC REST API calls is `https://www.exacttargetapis.com/`.

Comment: Thanks Adam. My problem ended up being kind of dumb - I wasn't signing in to the user because my organization uses SSO and the API user couldn't use SSO because it didn't exist outside of salesforce. But once I became aware of the fact that I could and in fact needed to sign in with the API user through the conventional sign-in strategy, everything else fell into place.


TL;DR for anyone who wants the answer to the question in my post's title: Yes, you do, you just need to log in with it on the web. It can't be done in the command line.