# Get Access Token

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I need to get access token for use it in API, below is example of my request

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken -d "{\"clientId\": \"Consumer Key\", \"clientSecret\": \"Consumer Secret\"}"
```

and response

```
{"message":"Unauthorized","errorcode":1,"documentation":""}
```

Maybe i forgot set some permissions, or configure something. Please help me. Also as alternative i appear id docs one more method to get access token with subdomain request url (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm), but i don't know, where i can get subdomain, i try to do something and now i have `https://MY_USERNAME-dev-ed.lightning.force.com` but MY_USERNAME-dev-ed is not valid subdomain, because it response me

```
Could not resolve host: MY_USERNAME-dev-ed.marketingcloudapis.com`
```

Any help will be very appreciate.

Comment: Do you mind checking the same question here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220420/i-have-an-api-user-id-and-secret-do-i-have-everything-i-need-to-get-an-api-toke

Comment: Where are you getting your clientid and clientsecret from? Be careful not to confuse force.com and Marketing cloud which use completely unrelated APIs:)

Comment: @Doug Yes, i get my credentials on force.com, where i can find credentials for marketing cloud?

Comment: @Naval\ Sharma i doesnt find the same tab in my interface as describe in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/create-a-mc-app.html, staring from third point

Comment: Hey! Check out administration ->account -> installed packages. There you can create an API integration app with clientid and clientsecret:)

Comment: @Doug in Administration tab i have only "User", "Data" and "Email"

Comment: In which case you likely don't have permissions. You'll need to ask your system admin about this:)

Comment: @Doug i think i am admin, i have register on salesfore.com and after login it redirect me to lightning.force.com